# How to get the skin of an SWT widget?

Tags: java, widget, swt, skin

I want to create an SWT Scale widget with two/multiple thumbs. The problem is that I want it to have the native skin on each platform and not a custom made skin.

Practically, I want to get the skin of every component of the widget and draw them myself.

Any ideas how to do that, or maybe an alternate solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT widgets don't have skins (as Swing widgets do), they are drawn by the native windowing toolkit (Win32, Gtk+, etc.).

Comment: Well.. ok.. I meant the image that the native toolkit draws for each element of the widget.

Comment: It may not use an image; the widget may likely be built up from a number of draw operations.

Comment: You're right. I've looked through the SWT widgets code and it seems that it's no more than a wrapper from which I cannot get any appearance data for the components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Riena Look and Feel:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena_Look_and_Feel

Answer (score 0):

While Peter's answer is correct, you could try to take screenshots of `Scale` with thumbs in different positions and overlay them. See http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.com/2007/01/tableviewers-and-nativelooking.html for an example of this technique.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, before SWT implements API for drawing controls:
first check if application is themed, and then use one or the other drawing API:

```
public void paintTheme(GC gc, Shell shell, Rectangle bounds)
    RECT rect = new RECT();
    rect.left = bounds.x;
    rect.right = bounds.x + bounds.width;
    rect.top = bounds.y;
    rect.bottom = bounds.y + bounds.height;
    if (OS.IsAppThemed()) {
        int theme = OS.OpenThemeData(shell.handle, className);
        OS.DrawThemeBackground(theme, gc.handle, partId, stateId, rect, null);
        OS.CloseThemeData(theme);
    } else {
        OS.DrawFrameControl(gc.handle, rect, uType, uState);
    }
}
```

You can find class names and part and state ids at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and types and states for non-themed API at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Please note that not all controls have non-themed type. I believe that the thumb for the scale should be a button in non themed applications.

Because the links above do not give you the values for the part, states and type values, I suggest getting them from the header files *winuser.h* and *vsstyle.h*.

Edit: for scale, in not themed applications I believe you have to use button for thumb. Also, I forgot to mention that this uses non documented API, and it is not portable.